# How to change the values of the dropdown when a change is triggerred

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change the value of the dropdown when a change in another dropdown is triggered.

```
<select id="option">
    <option id="1">1</option>
    <option id="2">2</option>
</select>


<select id="au">
    <option id="admin">admin</option>
    <option id="user">user</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" id="cb">hii
```

If I change the first dropdown `option` to `1`, the 2nd dropdown should change is value to admin and checkbox should be checked and both of them should be disaabled.

how can I do it?

Here's what I've tried.

```
$("#option").change(function() {
    $("#cb").prop('checked', true);

});
```

Comment: Sorry, Let me update my question with what I've tried.

Comment: Not sure if I am the only one wondering what is the purpose of the option 2

Comment: Instead of using ID for options, use VALUE attribute

Comment: Why so many downvotes? It's a genuine problem and is under SO guidelines.

Comment: Actually it is not but, anyways, questions like this get answered every second

Comment: And may I know why not?

Comment: IMHO, when your question reached the threshold of describing what you want as requesting for it instead of what you tried and why you couldn't succeed. Plus, I consider your question incomplete too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User attribute `value` to assign values.

HTML:

```
<option value="1" id="1">1</option>
<option value="2" id="2">2</option>

<option value="admin" id="admin">admin</option>
<option value="user" id="user">user</option>
```

JS:

```
$("#option").change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "1"){
        $("#au option[value='admin']").attr("selected","selected");
        $("#au").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#cb").prop("checked",true).attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
    else{
        $("#au").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#cb").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/tBNDy/2)

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the ID, and you should probably use a value instead, but anyway

```
$('#option').on('change', function() {
    var id = $('option:selected').prop('id');

    $('#admin').prop('selected', id == '1').closest('select').prop('disabled', id == '1');
    $('#cb').prop('checked', id == '1').prop('disabled', id == '1');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZawYD/)

The proper way, with values

[**ANOTHER FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZawYD/2/)

Comment: Thanks. But they are not disabled. How can I disable them as well?